# Memory efficiency of nested functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have the following functions:

```
def functionA(b, c):
    def _innerFunction(b, c):
        return b + c
    return _innerFunction(b, c)

def _outerFunction(b, c):
    return b + c

def functionB(b, c):
    return _outerFunction(b, c)
```

`functionA` and `functionB` will do the same. `_outerFunction` is globally available, while `_innerFunction` is only available for `functionA`. Nested functions are useful for data hiding and privacy, but what about their memory efficiency? For my understanding, the `_outerFunction` must only be loaded once, while the `_innerFunction` works like a "local" variable and hence must be loaded each time `functionA` is called. Is that correct?

Comment: You could look at the output of `dis.dis(functionA)` and `dis.dis(functionB)`. In this case, `functionB` executes `MAKE_FUNCTION, SORE_FAST and LOAD_FAST`, while `functionA` executes `LOAD_GLOBAL`; `functionA` also ends up calling `LOAD_FAST` twice per argument.

Comment: I'll have a look at this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding memory, both of them have almost the same memory footprint.

A function is comprised of a code object, containing the actual compiled code, and a function object containing the closure, the name and other dynamic variables.

The code object is compiled for all functions, inner and outer, before the code is run. It is what resides in the `.pyc` file.

The difference between an inner and an outer function is the creation of the function object. An outer function will create the function only once, while the inner function will load the same constant code object and create the function every run.

As the code object is equivalent, `_inner` and `_outer`'s memory footprint is equivalent:

- In both cases you have the name of the function as a constant. In the `functionA` the name will be used to construct the inner function object on each run, while in `functionB` the name will be used to refer to the global module and search for the outer function.
- In both cases you need to hold a code object, either in the global module or in `functionA`.
- In both cases you have the same parameters and same space saved for variables.

Runtime however is not equivalent: `functionB` needs to call a global function which is slightly slower than an inner function, but `functionA` needs to create a new function object on each run which is significantly slower.

---

In order to prove how equivalent they are, let's check the code itself:

```
>>> functionA.__code__.co_consts
(None, <code object _innerFunction at 0x00000296F0B6A600, file "<stdin>", line 2>, 'functionA.<locals>._innerFunction')
```

We can see the code object as a const stored inside `functionA`. Let's extract the actual compiled bytecode:

```
>>> functionA.__code__.co_consts[1].co_code
b'|\x00|\x01\x17\x00S\x00'
```

Now let's extract the bytecode for the outer function:

```
>>> _outerFunction.__code__.co_code
b'|\x00|\x01\x17\x00S\x00'
```

It's exactly the same code!

The local variable positions are the same, the code is written the same, and so the actual compiled code is exactly the same.

```
>>> functionA.__code__.co_names
()
>>> functionB.__code__.co_names
('_outerFunction',)
```

In `functionB`, instead of saving the name in the consts, the name is saved in a `co_names` which is later used for calling the global function.

The only difference in memory footprint is thus the code of `functionA` and `functionB`:

```
>>> functionA.__code__.co_code
b'd\x01d\x02\x84\x00}\x02|\x02|\x00|\x01\x83\x02S\x00'
>>> functionB.__code__.co_code
b't\x00|\x00|\x01\x83\x02S\x00'
```

`functionA` needs to create a function object on each run, and the name for the inner function includes `functionA.<locals>.`, which entails a few extra bytes (which is negligible) and a slower run.

---

In terms of runtime, if you're calling the inner function multiple times, `functionA` is slightly faster:

```
def functionA(b, c):
    def _innerFunction():
        return b + c
    for i in range(10_000_000):
        _innerFunction() # Faster

def _outerFunction(b, c):
    return b + c

def functionB(b, c):
    for i in range(10_000_000):
        _outerFunction(b, c) # Slower

def functionC(b, c):
    outerFunction = _outerFunction
    for i in range(10_000_000):
        outerFunction(b, c) # Almost same as A but still slower.

py -m timeit -s "import temp;" "temp.functionA(1,2)"
1 loop, best of 5: 2.45 sec per loop

py -m timeit -s "import temp;" "temp.functionB(1,2)" 
1 loop, best of 5: 3.21 sec per loop

py -m timeit -s "import temp;" "temp.functionC(1,2)" 
1 loop, best of 5: 2.66 sec per loop
```

If you're calling the outer function multiple times, `functionB` is significantly faster as you avoid creating the function object:

```
def functionA(b, c):  # Significantly slower
    def _innerFunction():
        return b + c
    return _innerFunction()

def _outerFunction(b, c):
    return b + c

def functionB(b, c):  # Significantly faster
    return _outerFunction(b, c)


py -m timeit -s "import temp;" "for i in range(10_000_000): temp.functionA(1,2)" 
1 loop, best of 5: 9.46 sec per loop

py -m timeit -s "import temp;" "for i in range(10_000_000): temp.functionB(1,2)" 
1 loop, best of 5: 5.48 sec per loop
```

---

@KellyBundy: What about recursion?

My answer is only true for sequential runs.

If the inner function recurses inside both A and B, there's no real difference in runtime or memory consumption, other than A being *slightly* faster. If function A and B recurse themselves, B will not allow a deeper recursion but will be significantly faster and will require less memory.

On a sequential run, there is no difference in memory as there is one function object either stored in the global module, or stored as a local variable that is constantly recreated. In case of outside (`A` | `B`) recursion there is a memory difference: The local variable where the `_innerFunction` object is stored is not cleared, meaning there is an additional function object created for every recursion inwards. In this specific example, we can see an important distinction between Python and other languages - Python does not have a [tail-call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), meaning the frames aren't reused and the variables aren't removed when we recurse inwards, even though no one will reference them anymore.

You're welcome to play with the following [visualization](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20functionA%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20_innerFunction%28b,%20c%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20b%20%2B%20c%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3E%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20functionA%28_innerFunction%28n,%20-1%29%29%0A%0Adef%20_outerFunction%28b,%20c%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20b%20%2B%20c%0A%0Adef%20functionB%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3E%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20functionB%28_outerFunction%28n,%20-1%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0AfunctionA%282%29%0AfunctionB%282%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

> I guess stack space is exactly identical, all differences are on the heap?

When you're working with Python, it's hard to divide things into a stack and heap. The C-stack is irrelevant as Python uses its own virtual stack. Python's stack is actually linked by the function's currently running frame, and is loaded, or created when a function is invoked. It is the reason they're also called stack frames - there's a linked list or "stack" of frames, and each frame has its own mini-stack called a value-stack. Both the stack and the frame are stored on the heap.

There are plenty of benefits for using this approach, and a nice anecdote would be generator functions. I've actually written [an article](https://towardsdatascience.com/cpython-internals-how-do-generators-work-ba1c4405b4bc) about the subject, but in short, being able to load and unload the stack at will, allows us to pause a function in the middle of its execution, and is the basis for both generators and asyncio.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. It helps me a lot.

Comment: @CLRW97 Further elaborated with examples.

Comment: So to conclude: if not necessary due to privacy, sticking with an outer function is preferable in terms of memory (negligible) and runtime?

Comment: @CLRW97 The memory difference is only due to the size of the function calling, which is almost irrelevant. The runtime isn't as negligible. Inner functions do have a different advantage in terms of runtime though - loading variables from a closure is faster. This is relevant when you're calling the inner function repeatedly as you don't need to load variables again and again. It requires changing how the inner one looks though, and not accepting any variables.

Comment: @CLRW97 I've added the runtimes.

Comment: What if `functionA` and `functionB` were recursive? Might it become significant then, `functionB` perhaps allowing deeper recursion?

Comment: @Kelly If the inner function recurses in both A and B, there's no difference, other than A being slightly faster. If function A and B recurse themselves, B will not allow a deeper recursion but will be significantly faster.

Comment: @Bharel I meant [each recurses itself](https://tio.run/##hZBNjsIwDIX3OYV3TZiCWkYafhZIsOASaFSVkEJE41SOu6gQZ@8UKCCYkcYry@/J37Orhg8eP6cVta11lSeG0ATRt0y5Ni4vS68hD8BOiJ0poKhRs/W4lKjmArq6TDOLaGjda3Ibg@7VS5HhmhC28AH6OrQFICwg@WV5bn/biDEMU6VuGTJf89@0F9JL3tUj77/wlXwDPODde0bBMBldU@iU0jrLMk0Gg5kS7EaBc2KpxPOM8XjylShRkUWWRXTqTHvD2fW5u8wZ56mRapN@z@NzdPdF/hiptv0B). On that site, both can recurse up to around 22760 levels without crashing. But tracemalloc shows 13.5 MB for A and 10.3 MB for B. So I guess stack space is exactly identical, all differences are on the heap?

Comment: @KellyBundy Edited my answer to clarify recursion. See the new section. Do note btw that afaik tracemalloc does not account for memory fragmentation, so its output should be taken with a grain of salt regarding real-life phenomena. In short - code that takes less memory in tracemalloc might actually take a larger chunk of RAM.

Comment: In the case of calling the inner function 10,000,000 times, you should get the same speedup with an outer function if you just write `outerFunction = _outerFunction` at the start of `functionB`, and then call it via the local variable.

Comment: @kaya3 umm not really. What you mention is a speedup, and a significant one as it avoids a global lookup, but another thing I was thinking of was accessing variables inside a closure (i.e. `nonlocal`) which is extremely fast unlike loading them in and out of the stack by passing to a function. Basically there are a few factors that come into play, some are minor, some are major, but no matter what, an inner function can almost always be written to work faster when approaching infinite invocations.

Comment: @kaya3 Added `functionC` for comparison. There's still a 10% difference, consistent across multiple runs.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you had changed the `_innerFunction` to not take parameters. Actually I'm a little surprised that accessing variables via a closure is faster than passing them normally.

Comment: @kaya3 It's 2 simple dereference operations: `_innerFunction.__code__.co_freevars` has the name of the closure variables, and `_innerFunction.__closure__` has the `cell` objects, or variables which points to the actual Python object. It is basically a pointer to a pointer. When Python is compiled, the actual bytecode tells it to go to the numbered cell object and dereference it twice (`LOAD_DEREF`). I can further explain the internal operation but it's out of scope for this particular question.

Comment: @kaya3 By the way, the speedups offered by closures should not be underestimated. I once [came across an article](https://late.am/post/2015/05/07/optimize-python-with-closures.html) where correct usage of closures made or broke a billion dollar company.